# How can I database insert after booting , network connect time?

Tags: android

I have occur problem.

recently , android device information insert DB.
macaddr , ip, public ip, boot time ...

but I don't know after booting, connect network time.

I want connect network time.

dataInsert is table name.

```
private SimpleDateFormat bootOnLan = new SimpleDateFormat(DBProxy.DateTimeFormat);

PreparedStatement statement = mConnection.prepareStatement(dataInsert);
statement.setString(1, bootOnLan.format(new Date(getOnLanTime())));




   public static String getOnLanTime(){
     Intent intent = null;
    String action = intent.getAction();

    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = null;
    Context context = BlackEyeActivity.getMainActivity();

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    int iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1: activeNetwork.getType();

    if(action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(iNetworkType == connectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET){
            return EthernetOnLan;
        }
        else if (iNetworkType == connectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return EthernetOnLan;
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    return EthernetOnLan;
}
```

this is not  DB INSERT
how can I programmatically on android ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please brief your question? 
To get to know Booting of device,

Write in manifest that :

```
<receiver android:name="com.prac.test.ServiceStarter">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And add permission in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Write a class that Receives the intent  :

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.prac.test.MyPersistingService");
        i.setClass(context, MyPersistingService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

Here you just save the time.

Try it.. It may helps..